# Cannot compile PHP 5.6 with Homebrew on Mac OS 10.12

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I am in trouble compiling PHP 5.6 using Brew on my Mac OS X 10.12 system.

My problem begins because even if I can install PHP 5.6 directly with `brew install php56`, the problem is that it is not using the correct php.ini file, witch should be taken from `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini`, but it seems to be taken from `/etc`:

```
m@MacBook-Pro-4.local:~$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

This is a problem because I cannot install any additional extension like **php56-redis** which I need.

So I would like to build PHP 5.6 from source to see if it will solve this problem, but when I start the build I get this error which I cannot solve even after searching on Google:

```
m@MacBook-Pro-4.local:~$ brew install php56 --build-from-source
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> New Formulae
kibana@5.6
==> Updated Formulae
kibana

==> Installing php56 from homebrew/php
==> Downloading https://php.net/get/php-5.6.32.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
Already downloaded: /Users/mattia/Library/Caches/Homebrew/php56-5.6.32
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.32_8 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.6 --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php/5.6 --with
Last 15 lines from /Users/mattia/Library/Logs/Homebrew/php56/01.configure:
checking for DSA_get_default_method in -lssl... no
checking for X509_free in -lcrypto... yes
checking for RAND_egd... no
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for OpenSSL version... >= 0.9.6
checking for CRYPTO_free in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_set_ssl_version in -lssl... yes
checking for PCRE library to use... bundled
checking whether to enable the SQLite3 extension... yes
checking bundled sqlite3 library... yes
checking for ZLIB support... yes
checking if the location of ZLIB install directory is defined... no
checking for zlib version >= 1.2.0.4... 1.2.8
checking for gzgets in -lz... no
configure: error: ZLIB extension requires gzgets in zlib
```

I tried to search on Google but I didn't find anything related to the `ZLIB extension requires gzgets in zlib` error.

I have the latest version of XCode installed.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Can you try php -v to see which version of PHP is running ?

Comment: I think I found the problem. The "php" command loads /usr/bin/php and not /usr/local/bin/php shipped from Homebrew, but /usr/local/bin is before /usr/bin in my $PATH do you have any idea?

Comment: Thats what I tough. You had a previous installation of PHP. Right ?

Comment: I think so, but I don't remember when and how I installed it.

Comment: My PATH is "/Users/m/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/m/.rvm/bin"

Comment: I think you must set the new PHP Path by this. I will post an answer right down. Please run php -v and tell me what you see.

Comment: php -v is m@MacBook-Pro-4.local:~$ php -v
PHP 5.6.32 (cli) (built: Nov 15 2017 18:20:43) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify to the system the PHP path by this way.

1. nano vim ~/.bash_profile
2. Then Add your current PHP path (for PHP 5.6 by this way)

   export PATH=/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/bin:$PATH
3. Then save and compile by running this command

   source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: PHP 5.6 from Homebrew is installed in /usr/local/bin, which already is into my PATH before /usr/bin. In fact I don't have the /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/bin directory on my system.